# Is it Possible to Use Histogram Facet or Its Curl Response in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, facet, kibana

Is it possible to use a manually created histogram facet (or the results of its curl request) like this one in a Kibana dashboard:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
        "histo1" : {
            "histogram" : {
                "key_script" : "doc['date'].date.minuteOfHour * factor1",
                "value_script" : "doc['num1'].value + factor2",
                "params" : {
                    "factor1" : 2,
                    "factor2" : 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will be supported in Kibana4, but there doesn't seem to be much more info out there than that.

For reference: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1249