# Retrieve count of total unique values kibana + Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Based on this question & answer "[How to retrieve unique count of a field using Kibana + Elastic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102220/how-to-retrieve-unique-count-of-a-field-using-kibana-elastic-search)"
I have been able to collect the individual count of the unique IP addresses from our Apache logs, however, What I actually want to do is to be able to display the count of the individual IP addresses, i.e. how many unique visitors.

I think I need to use the terms_stats facet to do this but I don't know what to set as the "value_field"

[image: Kibana terms panel]

Comment: Do you want a count of all the unique values?

Comment: I want a count of the number of unique values, i.e.
20 visits from 192.168.0.1
30 visits from 172.16.0.20
5 visits for 192.168.0.3
would return a value of 3, not 55

Comment: At the moment, I do not think it is possible to do with Kibana. You can get that number using aggregations (I think) in Elasticsearch, but there is nothing implemented in Kibana yet. This guy also has the same problem as you, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21998410/1004046

Comment: This looks like a great usecase for the new cardinaly aggregation, added in 1.1. Unfortunately not exposed yet in kibana.

Comment: If you still need it, you can use this pull request done by one of my colleagues: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/pull/1435/commits. It uses cardinality aggregation to get the count of distinct values.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the current version of the kibana.

but i have what i did to achieve this is created the custom histogram panel.

to create the custom histogram panel, just copy the existing histogram and modify config.js, module.js to change all the path references to the new panel.

override the doSearch function to use the query http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/count-elasticsearch/

and update the results parsing logic.

look for function

b.get_data = function(a, j, k)

```
                return b.populate_modal(n), p = n.doSearch(), p.then(function(c) {
                    if (b.panelMeta.loading = !1, 0 === j && (b.legend = [], b.hits = 0, a = [], b.annotations = [], k = b.query_id = (new Date).getTime()), d.isUndefined(c.error)) {
                        if (b.query_id === k) {
                            var i, n, p, q = 0;
                            o = JSON.parse("[{\"query\":\"*\",\"alias\":\"\",\"color\":\"#7EB26D\",\"id\":0,\"pin\":false,\"type\":\"lucene\",\"enable\":true,\"parent\" : 0}]");
                            d.each(o, function(e) {
                                //alert(JSON.stringify(c));
                                //var f = c.aggregations.monthly.buckets[e.id];                                 
                                if (d.isUndefined(a[q]) || 0 === j) {
                                    var h = {interval: m,start_date: l && l.from,end_date: l && l.to,fill_style: b.panel.derivative ? "null" : b.panel.zerofill ? "minimal" : "no"};
                                    i = new g.ZeroFilled(h), n = 0, p = {}
                                } else
                                    i = a[q].time_series, n = a[q].hits, p = a[q].counters;
                                d.each(c.aggregations.monthly.buckets, function(a) {
                                    var c;
                                    n += a.visitor_count.value, b.hits += a.visitor_count.value, p[a.key] = (p[a.key] || 0) + a.visitor_count.value, "count" === b.panel.mode ? c = (i._data[a.key] || 0) + a.visitor_count.value : "mean" === b.panel.mode ? c = ((i._data[a.key] || 0) * (p[a.key] - a.visitor_count.value) + a.mean * a.visitor_count.value) / p[a.key] : "min" === b.panel.mode ? c = d.isUndefined(i._data[a.key]) ? a.min : i._data[a.key] < a.min ? i._data[a.key] : a.min : "max" === b.panel.mode ? c = d.isUndefined(i._data[a.key]) ? a.max : i._data[a.key] > a.max ? i._data[a.key] : a.max : "total" === b.panel.mode && (c = (i._data[a.key] || 0) + a.total), i.addValue(a.key, c)
                                }), b.legend[q] = {query: e,hits: n}, a[q] = {info: e,time_series: i,hits: n,counters: p}, q++
                            }), b.panel.annotate.enable && (b.annotations = b.annotations.concat(d.map(c.hits.hits, function(a) {
                                var c = d.omit(a, "_source", "sort", "_score"), g = d.extend(e.flatten_json(a._source), c);
                                return {min: a.sort[1],max: a.sort[1],eventType: "annotation",title: null,description: "<small><i class='icon-tag icon-flip-vertical'></i> " + g[b.panel.annotate.field] + "</small><br>" + f(a.sort[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),score: a.sort[0]}
                            })), b.annotations = d.sortBy(b.annotations, function(a) {
                                return a.score * ("desc" === b.panel.annotate.sort[1] ? -1 : 1)
                            }), b.annotations = b.annotations.slice(0, b.panel.annotate.size))
                        }
                    } else
                        b.panel.error = b.parse_error(c.error);
                    b.$emit("render", a), j < h.indices.length - 1 && b.get_data(a, j + 1, k)
                })
```